# Connect to on-premises sql server from azure function with hybrid connection via service bus

Tags: sql, azure

I am trying to connect the sql server on my local computer from azure timer trigger  function using Hybrid connection with Service Bus and getting the error as

> "Exception while executing function: Functions.testConnection. mscorlib: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. .Net SqlClient Data Provider: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server). Access is denied.2017-06-28T11:20:00.015 Function started"

And this is the code:

[image: And this is the code]

sqldb_connection value is :

```
Data Source=103.249.120.30 ;Initial Catalog=databasename;User ID=id;Password=password;
```